# Azure API doesnt use connection string from configuration, but local one

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, connection-string, azure-api-management

I have connection string in azure api configuration with the same name, but when i go to api, swagger, it tells me - `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: LocalDB is not supported on this platform.`
returning 500 status.
this is how i get connection string from api:

```cs
private string _connectionString = string.Empty;

        public string GetConnectionString(string name)
        {
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json");
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile(path, false);

            var root = configurationBuilder.Build();
            _connectionString = root.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection(name).Value;
            var appSetting = root.GetSection("ApplicationSettings");

            return _connectionString;
        }
```

API project is on .net 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are building you configuration from file only, while you need to add `AddEnvironmentVariables` so it will add properties from Azure App Service Configuration

Try this:

```
  public string GetConnectionString(string name)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json");
            var root = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile(path, false)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            _connectionString = root.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection(name).Value;
            var appSetting = root.GetSection("ApplicationSettings");

            return _connectionString;
        }
```

Since its in library you need add package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables` which contains `AddEnvironmentVariables` extension.

The other way to do it would be to add FrameworkReference in your project but that would bring lots of asp.net core stuff you probably dont need

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: It says that IConfigurationBuilder does not contain a definition for `AddEnvironmentVariables`

Comment: try to add namespace using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

Comment: @komnen is that code in librarry or webapi project?

Comment: It's in library

edit: Oh, could that be a problem? I didnt publish my library yet

Comment: It worked! Thank you!
Can u please elaborate more on the issue in the answer?

Comment: @komnen done. Ask if you have any other questions